# How can I delete backed up Google+ photos off of the phone?

Tags: backup, photos, delete, google-backup, google-plus-photos

How can I delete backed up Google+ photos off of the phone? I know Flikr has support for this, and I don't think there is a way to do this natively with Google+, so is there a 3rd party app or utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Photos app, tap the hamburger menu (the three bars in the upper left corner), scroll down and choose `On Device`. You should be able to delete these without touching the backup. If you are prompted `Delete Everywhere`, select cancel, you are in the wrong place.

You could also use a file explorer app, such as ES File Explorer. Your photos are stored in DCIM>Camera. You should be able to select all and delete.

But if you are asking for something that will auto-delete them as you go, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Google Photos. Since they have recently been integrated with Google Drive, a new solution may arise soon.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to Google+ app and delete your photos from there.